# Can't log into OS X Server after restart

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, opendirectory, osx-leopard

Just restarted our Mac OS X Server (Leopard), and we are no longer able to log into the default user account, srvadmin!

This is an open directory account. We are presented with the login screen, but it responds as though the credentials are not recognised.

How can this be solved?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused do you have a local account on that server?  Can you log into other computers with that OD account?

Comment: Hi Scott, we have several local accounts of the server we are able to log in to, no problem. It just seems the open directory accounts are fubared.

Comment: Is that server an OD server and can you connect to OD with the Workgroup Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login using local account and check using Server Admin if there is OD running at all. Check log files namely PasswordServer, slapd and Directory Service. If there is anything relevant there, please post it here

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "srvadmin" is the account that you created when the OS was installed and configured.  If so, a few ideas:

1. Login as ANYONE and type "id srvadmin" to confirm that the account still exists.
2. Put in the OS install disk, reboot from it, and use the password change tool.

Good luck.  Ping me if you need more help.  This is a routine sort of thing for Mac sysadmins.  :)